# i want to integrate sentry exception handling in my vanilla.js project

Tags: javascript, html, libraries, sentry

this is my index.html file. I ahve included a script tag in head to load the sentry library for exception handling. also in the script tag in the end of body i have included sentry.init code. but the problem is that i am getting an error in browser console that

```
index.html:155 Uncaught ReferenceError: Sentry is not defined
    at index.html:155:11
```

also i think that sentry is not being loaded. it is also not showing in the network tab.

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Word Search</title>
        
        <meta name="Title" content="Word Search" />
        <meta name="description" content="Word Search is a HTML5 game where you have to solve word search puzzles covering a mix of both fun and educational categories, you can even create your very ownd custom puzzles.">
        <meta name="keywords" content="word, search, solve, education, custom, puzzle, brain , traditional, classic">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <script>
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
            var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
            msViewportStyle.appendChild(
                document.createTextNode(
                    "@-ms-viewport{width:device-width}"
                )
            );
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].
                appendChild(msViewportStyle);
        }
        </script>
<script
        src="https://1aa7cf70cefa4e7a8291ae243df33e10@o316195.ingest.sentry.io/4504791267082240"
      ></script>
      
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
        <!-- PERCENT LOADER START-->
        <div id="mainLoader"><img src="assets/loader.png" /><br/><span>0</span></div>
        <!-- PERCENT LOADER END-->
        
        <!-- CONTENT START-->
        <div id="mainHolder">
</div>
        <!-- CONTENT END-->
        <!-- <script src="/sentry.config.js"></script> -->
        <script>
          Sentry.init({
    dsn: "https://1aa7cf70cefa4e7a8291ae243df33e10@o316195.ingest.sentry.io/4504791267082240",
    integrations: [new BrowserTracing()],
  
    // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100%
    // of transactions for performance monitoring.
    // We recommend adjusting this value in production
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
  });
        </script>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
    </body>
```

my sentry setup is present in the above html code but if you find it hard to look at here is the snippet

```
<script
        src="https://1aa7cf70cefa4e7a8291ae243df33e10@o316195.ingest.sentry.io/4504791267082240"
      ></script>
Sentry.init({
    dsn: "https://1aa7cf70cefa4e7a8291ae243df33e10@o316195.ingest.sentry.io/4504791267082240",
    integrations: [new BrowserTracing()],
  
    // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100%
    // of transactions for performance monitoring.
    // We recommend adjusting this value in production
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
  });
```

Comment: When trying to fetch https://1aa7cf70cefa4e7a8291ae243df33e10@o316195.ingest.sentry.io/4504791267082240 - the server returns HTTP 404. You will need to load Sentry from a different, working URL.